# Why would using full buffers cause problems?

Tags: i2c

When reading [docs on Smbus2](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/), a Python i2c library, I found this statement:

> It is possible to write 32 bytes at the time, but I have found that
> error-prone. Write less and add a delay in between if you run into
> trouble.

I thought alright, I'll use less. But then I thought maybe I should not use the full buffer on the microcontrollers i2cs and other networks I work with. But that's inconvenient. Does anyone know why using a full buffer might cause errors? Would it be a good practice to always use a part of a buffer and not the entire buffer for i2c?

Edit: I just realized the smbus2 doc doesn't mention the buffer size explicitly. It occurred to me maybe there are chips with buffers less than 32 bytes. I started working with i2c recently have only seen 32 and 64 byte buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this 32 byte limit is really only limited by software.

A work around would simply use straight I2C which could theoretically be infinite byte sending/receiving or utilizing PMBus with a limitation of 255 bytes. The documentation for Python's SMBus2 library doesn't really explicitly say why 32 bytes is a hard limit but if I had to guess, it likely has to do with kernel limitations. Frankly, I don't know a lot about kernel's to talk about why that could be an issue.

I also do know that SMBus can timeout at higher physical layers, whereas I2C does not.